# Simple 'Logout' ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication, logout

I'm looking to create a very simple Logout page but falling at the first hurdle.

Here's my current Login page if it helps:
http://pastebin.com/2xJH1DnT

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   RegisterHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "Register.aspx?ReturnUrl=" + 
         HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
}
```

I tried initially using `FormsAuthentication.SignOut();` in my **logout** CodeBehind but kept getting the error:

> CS0103: The name 'FormsAuthentication' does not exist in the current context

How can I implement a log-out feature?

Comment: What are the errors your getting?

Comment: What error do you get. Can you post please?

Comment: what errors? Did you make you redirect the user to the login page after signing them out?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Error: `CS0103: The name 'FormsAuthentication' does not exist in the current context` in my CodeBehind ` protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
Line 11:     {
Line 12:         FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Line 13:     }
`

Comment: Can you please show the code that caused the error?

Comment: Hi Greg. Sorry for the delay. `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

which errors did you get? The right way should be:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage()
```

this applied if you are using Forms Authentication of course.

Comment: Only one of these methods is to be used at any one time - no need for both.

Comment: ok, then Microsoft is wrong here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.signout.aspx

Comment: Davide. That worked perfectly. It logged me out and redirected me. I think I'll now add this in place instead of a designated 'Logout' script.

Comment: No, they're not 'wrong', but there is no 'need' (see: requirement) to do so. Particularly if your application is set up for `FormsAuthentication` anyway, in which attempted access to an area that requires authorisation sees the user landing on the known login page.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Session.Abandon();

 FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
 Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm still getting the error: "CS0103: The name 'FormsAuthentication' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: then you need to add a using.